# Is there a way I can make a -script act on --find-file file?

Tags: emacs, elisp, text-processing

I want to text-process a bunch of html files with emacs, so I do:

```
find . -type f -name "*.html" | while read myFile; do
    emacs emacs --no-site-file --no-init-file --batch \
    -script myScript.el --find-file "$myFile"
done
```

The problem is to make `myScript.el` act on "$myFile" -- and save the modified "$myFile".

Perhaps one option will be to add a command line:

```
(add-to-list 'command-line-functions '(lambda () (and (message "ARG:'%s'" argi) t)))
```

to `.emacs` -- but then I'll have to load `.emacs` -- and I just don't need it loaded.

Perhaps it is better to put some wise lines in myScript.el.

**Edit**:

I just thought -- yet one more option will be to find files in myScript.el -- that is with `find-dired`.

**Edit 2**:

I'm having problem with `find-dired` approach for I can't get files marked:

```
(progn 
  (find-dired default-directory "-type f -name \"*.html\"")
  (dired-toggle-marks)
  )
```

doesn't work.

Comment: Since your (lambda ...) sexp is a function and not some random list data, you do not want to quote it.

Comment: @Stefan: You right. I wonder why it is working for example in `(add-to-list 'command-line-functions '(lambda () (and (message "ARG:'%s'" argi) t)))` and also `add-hook` and `global-set-key` can have lambda quoted.

Comment: I didn't say it won't work.  It's just a bad habit, and a quoted lambda won't behave quite like a non-quoted one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do it with the help of bash loop. I added

```
(setq myFile "/home/boris/pst/wordy/edu/PreWW/_build/html/test.html")
```

to myScript.el, and have run a loop:

```
find ./_build/html -type f -name '*.html' | while read myFile; do
    MyFile=`readlink -f "$myFile"`
    perl -ne "s!setq myFile .+!setq myFile \"$MyFile\")!" myScript.el
    emacs --no-site-file --no-init-file --batch -script myScript.el
done
```

which changes the script and then runs it.

Comment: @wvxvw: I agree that if I want to make use of emacs -- it is better to script the whole thing in emacs. I wanted to make use of emacs's find-dired -- but as You see in Edit 2 of the question -- I didn't get far.